# Log size is different between primary and secondary node with log_since_last_log_backup_mb

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, ola-hallengren

We get log backups from the secondary node. But now I see that log_since_last_log_backup_mb in sys.dm_db_log_stats returns null for databases which are in Availability groups, so Ola Hallengren's log backup procedure with

```
@LogSizeSinceLastLogBackup = 25,@TimeSinceLastLogBackup = 21000
```

limitations works on those databases. The backup process is currently working on the secondary node.

But I could not understand why it returns null? Have you encountered such a situation?

The following pictures show result of log size since last log backup on the primary and secondary nodes.

**Primary Node**

[image]

**Secondary Node**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect it to be `NULL` on the primary node if a backup has never happened on this node. You can confirm this by [checking when the last log backup happened](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3793858/6167855) for those databases on the primary node:

```
SELECT   d.name,
         d.dbid,
         MAX(b.backup_finish_date) AS backup_finish_date
FROM     master.sys.sysdatabases d
         LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb..backupset b
         ON       b.database_name = d.name
         AND      b.type          = 'L'
WHERE d.dbid in (19,34,21) --from your primary node
GROUP BY d.name, d.dbid
ORDER BY backup_finish_date DESC
```

And then on the secondary:

```
SELECT   d.name,
         d.dbid,
         MAX(b.backup_finish_date) AS backup_finish_date
FROM     master.sys.sysdatabases d
         LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb..backupset b
         ON       b.database_name = d.name
         AND      b.type          = 'L'
WHERE d.dbid in (19,34,33) --from your secondary node
GROUP BY d.name, d.dbid
ORDER BY backup_finish_date DESC
```

Comment: I am aware of this issue. I am in contact with Microsoft about it.

Comment: @OlaHallengren should it not return `NULL` if a backup hasn't happened on that node, especially if the node was the primary?

Comment: It looks like sys.dm_db_log_stats only has information in a few columns (database_id, recovery_model, and log_backup_time) when you query it on the secondary replica. All other columns are NULL.

I think that this is regardless of where log backups have been performed.

I will write back when I get an update from Microsoft.

Comment: I have been talking to Microsoft about this. Unfortunately it is by design. The documentation has been updated. "When running sys.dm_db_log_stats against a database that is participating in an Availability Group as a secondary replica, only a subset of the fields described above will be returned. Currently, only database_id, recovery_model, and log_backup_time will be returned when run against a secondary database."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-log-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017